# Union and Intersection of Indexed Family

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am currently trying to understand something that was stated in "Introduction to Analysis", it is the fifth edition. It is used for the Advance Calculus 1 course at ASU. I'm not taking the class right now but I want to get a jump on the material. I've taken an intro course on Logic and I've also taken a Discrete Mathematics course.

I think I understand these two definitions well. The first is "Let $\Lambda$ be a set, and suppose for each $\lambda\in\Lambda$, a subset $A_\lambda$ of a given set S is specified. The collection of sets $A_\lambda$ is called an $\textit{indexed family}$ of subsets of S with $\Lambda$ as the index set. We denote this by $\{A_\lambda\}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$".

The second is:
If $A_\lambda$ is an indexed family of sets, define
$$\bigcap_{\lambda\in\Lambda} A_\lambda=\{x:x \in A_\lambda, \text{for all }\lambda \in \Lambda\}$$
and
$$\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda} A_\lambda=\{x:x \in A_\lambda, \text{for some } \lambda \in \Lambda\}$$
The book states that if $\Lambda$ is empty then the union will be the empty set but that it is unclear what to expect from the intersection. I don't understand why that is. If $\Lambda$ is empty then doesn't that mean that there is no index for $A_\lambda$ and that there is no way of creating the intersection and union of $A_\lambda$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The union with empty index should be any set rather than empty. There are mainly 2 reasons for it. 
First, if all $A_{\lambda}$ are same, to be consistent with Idempotence of set the union should be $A_{\lambda}$ even if index is empty. More precisely, if for all $\lambda \in \Lambda, \: A_{\lambda}=A$, then
$$
\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda} A_\lambda=A
$$
Thus union with empty index should be 
$$
\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Phi} A_\lambda=A
$$
Second, if union with empty index is empty, then as you see, intersection would be universe by De Morgan's law, which makes no sense since intuitively union is always larger than intersection.

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly then the union should be any other set other than empty because if it is empty then it would lead to a contradiction because it would imply that the intersection is the universe? Also, would we not know what the union is with an empty $\Lambda$ where all $A_\lambda$ might not be the same?

Comment: Yes,your understanding is right. If they are not same, the union could be any set